# VBA code pastes the previous data to the new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, clipboard, copy-paste

I have a code which will copy the power query output table to the new workbook. If I execute the code one by one (using F8). it works fine. But when assign the same macro to the button & click this button to run macro. It pastes previous data of the power query output table to the new workbook. Its not pasting the latest data of input table.

I have tried to clear the clipboard. & checked whether power query table is getting refreshed. (after macro run i checked the PQ table & it refreshed). I wanted to know why this macro is not taking latest data to the paste it in a new workbook. I am using Applicaitoncutcopymode as false.

Comment: Seeing the code would help figuring out what's wrong with it :) Please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

What is likely happening is that you are doing a refresh and then copying before the refresh has finished. In the Query properties window, ensure `Enable background refresh` **is not** selected.

Comment: Did this answer your question?